# long int high and low bits pointers

Tags: c, pointers, long-integer, allocation

I'm trying to implement improved sequential multiplication algorithm in C. where the size of the product register is two times the size of the multiplicand and multiplier. in C an int is of 4 bytes and a long int makes it 8 bytes. I wanted to access the higher and lower 32-bits independently. so I pointed the lower and upper bits like:

```
long long int product = 0;
int* high = &product;
int* low = &product;
low++;
```

but this didn't work because I thought that if an int is allotted 4 bytes then a long int would be allotted 8 bytes and the pointer would be pointing to the MSB of the allocated memory. I'm not sure if this is actually how allocation is done. can anyone please help me clear this confusion.

I solved the problem using by doing this:

```
long long int product=0;
int* low = &product;
int* high = &product;
high++;
```

but I'm still confused that why is it working correctly;

Comment: The size of the product should be the sum of the size of the operands.

Comment: You need to be aware of endianness.

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: Endianess definitely plays a role, but does the C standard guarantee at all that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long long) / 2`? Does it really make sense to use a signed integer type for the lower part? Is it guaranteed that the `int`s are correctly aligned? On x86, this might not play a role if alignment check is disabled, but C is intended to be portable. And does this conform to the strict-aliasing rule? (I don't think so, but I'd have to look it up in the standard.) I think your construct is pretty much undefined and you'd be way better off just using a `union` or something comparable.

Comment: To make your code more portable, you might consider bit shifting and masking (operators >> and &). `unsigned int low = (unsigned int)(product & 0xFFFFFFFF)` and `unsigned int high = (unsigned int)(product >> 32)`. You would do `product = ((long long int)(high)) << 32 | low` at the end to update product.

Comment: Nearly all architectures nowadays are little-endian byte order.

Comment: Accessing an object of type `long long int` through an lvalue expression of type `int` is undefined behavior. You cannot use this approach.

Comment: "in C an `int` is of 4 bytes and a `long int` makes it 8 bytes" - that's fundamentally wrong. t is not even correct for the three major platforms Win, Linux and OSX/IOS.

Comment: @PongthepKulkrisada: Nonsense! There are still a lot of big-endian CPUs.

Comment: @Olaf: Sorry I wrongly typed. I should have said...
Most computers in the market nowadays are intel-based and little-endian byte order.

Comment: @PongthepKulkrisada: That's also wrong! Most computers are still 8 bit of various architectures, but mostly 8051 derivates, AVR and PIC and some 16 bitters. Then the ARM Cortex-M from a variety of manufacturers, **then** ARM Cortex-A. Each group alone outnumbers Intel-CPUs by a decade or more. FYI: Some x86 CPUs have integrated ARM cores, too!

Comment: @Olaf: Nah...don't count mobile devices. ;-p

Comment: @PongthepKulkrisada: You ignore >99% of all computers not to admit you were wrong. Not a good attitude.

Comment: Thankyou all of You. You guys got me an A :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using a computer that is [Little-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). On a little-endian machine, the least significant byte is first.